# further use of regex_matchNr in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

i really tried to find an answer but i couldn't.

I try to use the regex reference_matchNr to increment a user defined variable.
But i get always the following error msg:

```
${__intSum(${summe},${count1},summe)};

jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${count1}"
```

or

```
${__intSum(${summe},"${count1}",summe)};

jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""${count1}""
```

or

```
${__intSum(${summe},count1,summe)};

jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "count1"
```

I used the following code to get the matchNr value:

```
int count1 = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("status_matchNr"));
```

The strange thing is i'm able to write the value in the `jmeter log(log.info)` or in a file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you're using __intSum() function inside the Beanshell Assertion to add 2 values.

This is not gonna work as the function gets interpreted before the assertion hence your `count1` variable is not defined by the moment of function execution.

So workarounds are:

1. Use "Parameters" input for function evaluation prior interpreting the assertion. You ain't gonna need to convert your "status_matchNr" variable to integer, intSum function will do it for you. So if you put the following line to "Parameters"

   ```
   ${__intSum(${summe},${status_matchNr},summe)};
   ```

   It assumes that "summe" variable is defined and can be cast to an integer

   [image: Intsum and Beanshell assertion]
2. Go the "code only" way - perform sum of 2 integers purely in Beanshell code like:

   ```
   int count1 = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("status_matchNr"));
   int summe = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("summe"));
   summe += count1;
   vars.put("summe", String.valueOf(summe));
   //your assertion logic here
   ```

May I also recommend considering switching from Beanshell to [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and groovy language as Beanshell has performance problems and may become a bottleneck if your load is high. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for details, groovy scripting engine installation instructions and different scripting approaches benchmark.